# Correct Html Float in my website

Tags: html, css, css-float

I make a website it like a search engine for software.But here is a HTML or CSS problem in website.check out given url.
http://www.azelead.tk/search.php?search=skype
If you see the search result content in your browser then it.your browser support this if not please see what is the problem with that and how can i fix this.
FOR CODE:  go on this website and right click and then click show source code.
Here is all css and html code is present.
**UPDATE :**

Here is a css code

```
 #navBar{
margin:20px 0px 20px 0px;}  
 #navBar a{
display:block;
width:134.7px;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:16px;
color:#FFF;
background-color:#06F;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border:1px solid #0099FF;
padding:10px 0 10px 0;
float:left;}
 #navBar a:hover, #result a:hover{
background-color:#FFF;
color:#06F;}
 #downDiv{
margin-top:10px;
border:1px solid #00BBFF;
overflow:hidden;}   
 #searchContent{
margin-top:30px;
border:2px solid #0099FF;
background-color:#FFFFCC;
padding:7px 7px 7px 7px;
width:600px;
color:#0D2E57;
float:left;}
```

Here is html code.

```
<body>
  <div id="navBar">
            <b><a href="index.html">Search</a>
            <a href="dailysoft.html">Daily Soft</a>
            <a href="addsite.html">Add Site</a>
            <a href="contactus.html">Contact us</a>
            <a href="TermsAndConditions.html">Terms & Cond.</a>
            <a href="javascript:feedback('RFB');">FeedBack us</a>
            <a href="javascript:errorReport('RER');">Error Report</a></b>
        </div>
    <div id="downDiv">
            <div id="searchContent">
            I want this div in down side of the nav bar<br />
            other content goes here any sample content.<br />
    </div>
 <div>
 This is another div which I want on the right hand side<br />
 of the div search content.
 </div>     

 </body>
```

Comment: Please post code to stackoverflow. Otherwise, if your site ever goes down this question will be useless.

Comment: Also, it's *your* job to figure out which browsers are not supporting your code, not ours

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

1. Remove `float:left; display:block` from your navbar links, and add `display:inline-block` instead - you may need to adjust some sizes or get rid of all whitespace between them, but it works.
2. OR: Add `clear:both` to the downDiv element